# Set Cron depending on user input in configuration

Tags: magento-1.8, cron

In custom module's configuration, we allow admin to select a day when a task needs to be executed.

How do I specify that value dynamically in cron schedule?

for eg: Admin selected 20 in the settings page, then I need the cron schedule like this: 
`* * 20 * *`

Please let me know if anyone have achieved this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the cron to minimum reasonable interval (e.g. each 5 minutes) and then check inside of your module if the job has to be executed according to config settings.

Comment: So, there isn't a way to dynamically set the cron, right?

Anyways, your solution is nice and simple. I will set my cron to run that task every day and if the date is same as selected by Admin, then I will perform the desired task. Cool tip. Thanks Tim :)

Comment: Checking inside your module means you get to handle all the fun bits of date/time comparison. Not too mention duplicating the same system you're hooking into. The better approach is just write out the change to the modules config.xml nodes. http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php in particular generate() function.

Answer (score 1):

> In your modules config.xml put the following:
>
> ```
> <config>
>   <global>
>       <models>
>           <roomstoryinvoicecron>
>               <class>Roomstory_Invoice_Model</class>
>           </roomstoryinvoicecron>                         
>       </models>
>   </global>
>   <crontab>
>       <jobs>
>           <roomstoryinvoicecron>
>               <schedule><cron_expr>*/10 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
>               <run><model>roomstoryinvoicecron/observer::setStatus</model></run>
>           </roomstoryinvoicecron>
>       </jobs>
>   </crontab>
> </config>
> ```
>
> In app/code/local/Roomstory/Invoice/Model/Observer.php add the
>   following:
>
> ```
> <?php
> class Roomstory_Invoice_Model_Observer {
>     public function setStatus() {
>       Mage::log("WORKS!");
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Make sure logging is enabled and it should work, check the log to be
>   sure ;)

Source: 
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202463/how-to-setup-a-cron-job-in-magento-module

- http://www.nicksays.co.uk/dissecting-the-magento-cron-system/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290868/how-would-test-cron-with-magento
- http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-cron-scheduler.html

Comment: Thanks boomer, however, I wanted to know how to set cron dynamically. In your example you have set cron to run every 10 minutes. How can you make it to run every X day of month. X will be specified by Admin in config settings.